# ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. while running executable jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have one spring application(**dependency**) as a lib and other is simple java application(**dependenct**). I am trying to run java class from which i am calling spring main method. after running java -cp dependent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.dependent.DependentApplication it is giving me below:

> ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:456)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:438)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:431)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:262)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:241)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
> at com.example.dependency.DependencyApplication.main(DependencyApplication.java:11)
> at com.example.dependent.DependentApplication.main(DependentApplication.java:11)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
> at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:449)
> ... 8 more

**Pom.xml for spring application (dependency)below.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dependency</name>
    <description>dependency project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.dependency.DependencyApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Dependent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependent</artifactId>
    <name>dependent</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```